# @Value working for one class, but not the other

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I'm struggling with @Value annotation in my API.

My values are stored in the application.properties file in Spring Boot.

```
secretKey=trullySecretKey
```

I created one @Component class for a JWT Key:

```
@Component
public class SecretKeyProperties {

@Value("${secretKey}")
private String secretKey;

public String getSecretKey() {
    return this.secretKey;
}
```

}

And using it ar my JWT class:

```
@Service
public class JwtUtil {

@Autowired
SecretKeyProperties secretKeyProperties;

private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKeyProperties.getSecretKey()).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
}...
```

Works fine.

But when I do exactly the same, but with a Component for Mail properties setup:

```
    #Mail properties

auth=mail.smtp.auth
authValue=true
starttls=mail.smtp.starttls.enable
starttlsValue = true
host=mail.smtp.host
hostValue=smtp.gmail.com
ssl=mail.smtp.ssl.enable
sslValue=true
sender=test@email.com
password=myPassword
```

The class:

```
@Component
public class MailProperties {

@Value("${auth}")
private String auth;

@Value("${starttls}")
private String starttls;

@Value("${host}")
private String host;

@Value("${ssl}")
private String SSL;

@Value("${authValue}")
private boolean authValue;

@Value("${starttlsValue}")
private boolean starttlsValue;

@Value("${hostValue}")
private String hostValue;

@Value("${sslValue}")
private boolean sslValue;

@Value("${sender}")
private String sender;

@Value("${password}")
private String password;


public String getAuth() {
    return this.auth;
}

public String getStarttls() {
    return this.starttls;
}

public String getHost() {
    return this.host;
}

public String getSsl() {
    return this.ssl;
}

public boolean getAuthValue() {
    return this.authValue;
}

public boolean getStarttlsValue() {
    return this.starttlsValue;
}

public String getHostValue() {
    return this.hostValue;
}

public boolean getSslValue() {
    return this.sslValue;
}

public String getSender() {
    return this.sender;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}
```

And the implementation:

```
@Service
public class MessageBuilder {

@Autowired
MailProperties mailProperties;

public static Properties properties;
public static Session session;

public Properties setupProperties(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    
    properties.put(mailProperties.getAuth(), mailProperties.getAuthValue());
    properties.put(mailProperties.getStarttls(), mailProperties.getStarttlsValue());
    properties.put(mailProperties.getHost(), mailProperties.getHostValue());
    properties.put(mailProperties.getSsl(), mailProperties.getSslValue());

    return properties;
}
```

I get an error

```
 Cannot invoke "com.plaincoded.restapi.configuration.MailProperties.toString()" because "this.mailProperties" is null
```

It would make sense if it did not work on both occasions, but only in one?

Why could that be?

Update:

[image: FolderStructure]

Comment: How do you work with `MessageBuilder`? In which packages do the files reside?

Comment: @MarkBramnik I updated the post with package structure

Comment: And a couple of  heads up questions: 1. Who calls `setupProperties` please add code snippet for that as well? 2. Do the mail properies also reside in `src/main/resources/application.properties`?